# I Need help in writing a multi-level ms access subquery

Tags: ms-access, subquery

I am having hard time to wrap my mind around a multi-level query/sub-query. In short, I a table called REGISTER with 3 fields in it: TransactionId (PK), TransDate (DateTime), Amount (Currency). I need a single query to retrieve the TransactionId where TransDate is the Max and the Amount is the Min qualifying records. For example, if the max of qualifying record returns 5 records with today's date (any future dates is excluded), I would like to know the TransactionId of the lowest Amount within the 5 records returned.

I amble to accomplish this task with two separate query but I am sure it cab be done with a single one.

Query 1 (qryFlag):

```
SELECT REGISTER.TransDate, REGISTER.*
FROM REGISTER
WHERE (((REGISTER.TransDate)=(
  SELECT Max(t2.Transdate) from REGISTER t2 
  where Transdate <= Date())));
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT REGISTER.TransactionId
FROM qryFlag INNER JOIN REGISTER ON qryFlag.TransactionId = REGISTER.TransactionId
WHERE (((qryFlag.Amount)=(SELECT Min(t2.Amount) from qryFlag t2)));
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with splitting in 2 queries if you connect them by naming. In opposite, by splitting you can use query1 seperate without creating an additional query  and shorter queries are easier to manage. It is similar to vba code, where you try to extract code to methods, to imporove readabillity and reuseabillity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY TransDate` to get the min amount and then join to the table:

```
SELECT r.* 
FROM REGISTER AS r INNER JOIN ( 
  SELECT TransDate, MIN(Amount) AS MinAmount 
  FROM REGISTER
  WHERE TransDate = (SELECT Max(Transdate) FROM REGISTER WHERE Transdate <= Date())
  GROUP BY TransDate
) AS g on g.TransDate = r.TransDate AND g.MinAmount = r.Amount
```

Comment: forpas, if you don't mind, how can your code can be modified so that I can actually run a update query on that record? e.g. UPDATE REGISTER AS r INNER JOIN (SELECT TransDate, MIN(Amount) AS MinAmount 
  FROM REGISTER
  WHERE TransDate = (SELECT Max(Transdate) FROM REGISTER WHERE Transdate <= Date())
  GROUP BY TransDate
)  AS g ON (r.Amount = g.MinAmount) AND (r.TransDate = g.TransDate) SET r.Flag = True;

Comment: If you want to update the row with that TransactionId:  `UPDATE REGISTER 
SET Flag = True
WHERE TransactionId = 
(SELECT r.TransactionId 
FROM REGISTER AS r INNER JOIN ( 
  SELECT TransDate, MIN(Amount) AS MinAmount 
  FROM REGISTER
  WHERE TransDate = (SELECT Max(Transdate) FROM REGISTER WHERE Transdate <= Date())
  GROUP BY TransDate
) AS g on g.TransDate = r.TransDate AND g.MinAmount = r.Amount)`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT TOP 1 VTID.TransactionID
FROM (
SELECT TransactionID, Amount
FROM Register
WHERE TransDate = (SELECT Max(R.TransDate) FROM Register as R WHERE R.TransDate <= Date())
) as VTID
ORDER BY VTID.Amount
```

HTH

Dale